# Need to create new <w:r> for each character in <w:t>. - docx4j

Tags: openxml, docx4j

Let's take, first <w:r> from the below sample input. In that <w:t> contains Fig 1. Now I need to create new <w:r> for each character in <w:t>. (i.e) **F** should be in separate <w:r>, **i** should be in separate <w:r>, **g** should be in separate <w:r> and so on. Like the below structure.

```
 <w:r><w:t>F</w:t></w:r>
 <w:r><w:t>i</w:t></w:r>
 <w:r><w:t>g</w:t></w:r>
 <w:r><w:t> </w:t></w:r>
 <w:r><w:t>1</w:t></w:r>
 <w:r><w:t>.</w:t></w:r>
```

**Code Snippet:**

```
if (run.getParent() instanceof ContentAccessor) { 
 parent = (ContentAccessor) run.getParent(); 
 List<Object> childElements = getAllchildObj(run);
  if (childElements.size() > 0) {
   for (Object child : childElements) {
    int currentRunIndex = parent.getContent().indexOf(run);
    if (child.getClass().getName() == "org.docx4j.wml.RPr") {
            continue;
    }
  if (child instanceof Text) {
   String txt = ((Text) child).getValue();
   List<String> textElementString = textSplit(txt);
  for (String textElement : textElementString) {
     R newRun = factory.createR();
     newRun.setParent(parent);
     RPr tempRunProps = run.getRPr();
    if (tempRunProps != null) {
      String stringRunProps = XmlUtils.marshaltoString(tempRunProps);
    if (stringRunProps != null || stringRunProps.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
     newRun.setRPr((RPr) XmlUtils.unmarshalString(stringRunProps));
  }
}
     Text t = factory.createText();
     t.setSpace("preserve");
     t.setValue(textElement);
     newRun.getContent().add(t);
     try {
     parent.getContent().add(currentRunIndex, newRun);
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    logger.error("PM-324e55dc-b928-4c8f-9ecc-bce47b8cb54b: IndexOutOfBoundsException"+e.getMessage());
         }
    }
}else {
     R newRun = factory.createR();
     newRun.setParent(parent);
     currentRunIndex = parent.getContent().indexOf(run);
     RPr runProps = factory.createRPr();
     RPr tempRunProps = run.getRPr();
     if (tempRunProps != null) {
      String stringRunProps = XmlUtils.marshaltoString(tempRunProps);
     if (stringRunProps != null || stringRunProps.equalsIgnoreCase(""){
      newRun.setRPr((RPr) XmlUtils.unmarshalString(stringRunProps));
           }
       }
     newRun.getContent().add(child);
     parent.getContent().add(currentRunIndex, newRun);
      }
   }
}
    parent.getContent().remove(run);
}
```

The above snippet is working fine. If the run.getParent() is instance of ContentAccessor. Here for the below input, I'm not getting the expected output because <w:r> present inside <w:moveTo> (RunTrackChange). How I need to process, if run.getParent() is instance of RunTrackChange.

**Sample input:**

```
<w:p>
<w:pPr>
<w:pPrChange w:author="Judi Nath" w:date="2021-02-26T11:39:00Z" w:id="18">
  <w:pPr>
    <w:spacing w:line="360" w:lineRule="auto" />
    <w:ind w:left="-480" />
  </w:pPr>
</w:pPrChange>
 </w:pPr>
 <w:bookmarkStart w:name="para10020" w:id="10020" />
 <w:moveToRangeStart w:author="Judi Nath" w:date="2021-02-26T11:39:00Z" w:name="move65231970" w:id="19" />
 <w:proofErr w:type="gramStart" />
 <w:moveTo w:author="Judi Nath" w:date="2021-02-26T11:39:00Z" w:id="20">
<w:r>
  <w:rPr>
    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" />
    <w:b/>
    <w:sz w:val="24" />
  </w:rPr>
  <w:t>Fig 1.</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:proofErr w:type="gramEnd" />
<w:del w:author="Judi Nath" w:date="2021-02-26T11:39:00Z" w:id="23">
<w:r>
  <w:rPr>
    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" />
    <w:sz w:val="24" />
  </w:rPr>
  <w:delText xml:space="preserve"> A</w:delText>
</w:r>
</w:moveTo>
<w:bookmarkEnd w:id="10020" />
</w:p>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<w:p>
<w:pPr>
<w:pPrChange w:author="Judi Nath" w:date="2021-02-26T11:39:00Z" w:id="18">
  <w:pPr>
    <w:spacing w:line="360" w:lineRule="auto" />
    <w:ind w:left="-480" />
  </w:pPr>
</w:pPrChange>
 </w:pPr>
 <w:bookmarkStart w:name="para10020" w:id="10020" />
 <w:moveToRangeStart w:author="Judi Nath" w:date="2021-02-26T11:39:00Z" w:name="move65231970" w:id="19" />
 <w:proofErr w:type="gramStart" />
 <w:moveTo w:author="Judi Nath" w:date="2021-02-26T11:39:00Z" w:id="20">
<w:r>
  <w:rPr>
    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" />
    <w:b/>
    <w:sz w:val="24" />
  </w:rPr>
  <w:t>F</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r>
  <w:rPr>
    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" />
    <w:b/>
    <w:sz w:val="24" />
  </w:rPr>
  <w:t>i</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r>
  <w:rPr>
    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" />
    <w:b/>
    <w:sz w:val="24" />
  </w:rPr>
  <w:t>g</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r>
  <w:rPr>
    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" />
    <w:b/>
    <w:sz w:val="24" />
  </w:rPr>
  <w:t> </w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r>
  <w:rPr>
    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" />
    <w:b/>
    <w:sz w:val="24" />
  </w:rPr>
  <w:t>1</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r>
  <w:rPr>
    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" />
    <w:b/>
    <w:sz w:val="24" />
  </w:rPr>
  <w:t>.</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:proofErr w:type="gramEnd" />
<w:del w:author="Judi Nath" w:date="2021-02-26T11:39:00Z" w:id="23">
<w:r>
  <w:rPr>
    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" />
    <w:sz w:val="24" />
  </w:rPr>
  <w:delText xml:space="preserve"> </w:delText>
</w:r>
<w:r>
  <w:rPr>
    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" />
    <w:sz w:val="24" />
  </w:rPr>
  <w:delText xml:space="preserve">A</w:delText>
</w:r>
</w:moveTo>
<w:bookmarkEnd w:id="10020" />
</w:p>
```

Comment: Please expand on your question to make what you are asking clearer

Comment: @JasonPlutext Let me know whether its clear now.